# Ionic (pluginName: statusbar) does not exist, can't change statusbar font color

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework

I was having trouble changing the font color on the status bar in an ionic / cordova iOS app to white despite following having the statusbar plugin installed:

```
cordova plugins
...
org.apache.cordova.statusbar 0.1.8 "StatusBar"
```

and in app.js

```
.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    if(window.StatusBar) {
      StatusBar.styleLightContent();
    }
  });
})
```

and in config.xml

```
<preference name="StatusBarOverlaysWebView" value="true" />
<preference name="StatusBarStyle" value="lightcontent" />
```

The font color wasn't changing from black and I was getting error messages in the XCode console:

```
CDVPlugin class CDVStatusBar (pluginName: statusbar) does not exist.
```

for reference, my cordova version is `3.5.0-0.2.6` and ionic `1.0.0-beta.13`

Answer (score 8):

My solution was to remove and re-add the platforms.

```
cordova platform rm ios
cordova platform add ios
```